# How to avoid the useState function parameter (to get initial values) from being executed on every render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

See form the snippet below that the `getInitialState` is executed on every render. Even though the value returned from it is only used during the 1st render.

I know this is normal Javascript behavior. But is there a way to avoid it using React?

```js
function App() {

  function getInitialState() {
    console.log('Executing getInitialState...');
    return({
      foo: 'bar'
    });
  }

  const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState(getInitialState());
  const [myBoolean,setMyBoolean] = React.useState(false);
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am App</div>
      <div>My state: {JSON.stringify(myState)}</div>
      <div>My boolean: {JSON.stringify(myBoolean)}</div>
      <button onClick={()=>setMyBoolean((prevState) => !prevState)}>Force Update</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: why do you need it to be a function rather a constant?

Comment: @skyboyer it's possible the asker is determining the state from an API response or a similar dynamic source. Then a function would become necessary.

Comment: @ADTC well, async call for a `useState` initialization will never work. So the only need for "avoid calculation of initial value on every render" is only "it's too heavy".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't call the function directly inside the `useState`, pass an anonymous function to trigger the function. Refer to the official [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily).

```js
  function getInitialState() {
    console.log('Executing getInitialState...');
    return({
      foo: 'bar'
    });
  }
  
function App() {

  const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState(()=>getInitialState());
  const [myBoolean,setMyBoolean] = React.useState(false);
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am App</div>
      <div>My state: {JSON.stringify(myState)}</div>
      <div>My boolean: {JSON.stringify(myBoolean)}</div>
      <button onClick={()=>setMyBoolean((prevState) => !prevState)}>Force Update</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thats a good answer but you should elaborate on why and how it happens.

Comment: `getInitialState()` will excute the function every time but `() => getInitialState()` will pass the reference for the function so it will be called one time.

Comment: React will handle the `useState` differently according to the arguments. In your code, `getInitialState()` will return a value. And `useState` will treat a function reference differently. If it's a function, it will be executed only on the initial render

Answer (score 6):

You need to compute your state inside a function as per [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
const [myState,setMyState] = useState(() => {
  const initialState = getInitialState();
  return initialState;
});
```

Or shorter:

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(getInitialState);
```

Yet another hook gotcha!

Answer (score 2):

Try memoization  with [`React.useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```js
function getInitialState() {
  console.log('Executing getInitialState...');
  return {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
}

function App() {
  const getInitial = React.useMemo(() => getInitialState(), []);
  const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState(getInitial);
  const [myBoolean, setMyBoolean] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div> I am App </div>
      <div> My state: {JSON.stringify(myState)} </div>
      <div> My boolean: {JSON.stringify(myBoolean)} </div>
      <button onClick={() => setMyBoolean(prevState => !prevState)}>
        Force Update
      </button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 2):

All good solutions, my two cents = Dominic's shorter solution above. :)

You're passing a computed function (the result of the function is passed to useState) If you pass your function, React knows that it needs to call that function only the first time:

```js
function App() {

  function getInitialState() {
    console.log('Executing getInitialState...');
    return({
      foo: 'bar'
    });
  }

  const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState(getInitialState); // <-- pass the function, not the call to the function (result)
  const [myBoolean,setMyBoolean] = React.useState(false);
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>I am App</div>
      <div>My state: {JSON.stringify(myState)}</div>
      <div>My boolean: {JSON.stringify(myBoolean)}</div>
      <button onClick={()=>setMyBoolean((prevState) => !prevState)}>Force Update</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```